Expo development build fails on both iOS and Android targets
I'm trying to build a development build of Expo for iOS using expo@52.0.0-preview.23 but the build fails with the following.

❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoFetchCustomExtension.swift:9:75)

   7 | public class ExpoFetchCustomExtension: NSObject {
   8 |   @objc
>  9 |   public static func setCustomURLSessionConfigurationProvider(_ provider: NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider?) {
     |                                                                           ^ cannot find type 'NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider' in scope
  10 |     urlSessionConfigurationProvider = provider
  11 |   }
  12 | }


❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoFetchModule.swift:6:47)

  4 | 
  5 | private let fetchRequestQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "expo.modules.fetch.RequestQueue")
> 6 | internal var urlSessionConfigurationProvider: NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider?
    |                                               ^ cannot find type 'NSURLSessionConfigurationProvider' in scope
  7 | 
  8 | public final class ExpoFetchModule: Module {
  9 |   private lazy var urlSession = createURLSession()


❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoFetchModule.swift:10:35)

   8 | public final class ExpoFetchModule: Module {
   9 |   private lazy var urlSession = createURLSession()
> 10 |   private let urlSessionDelegate: URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy
     |                                   ^ cannot find type 'URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy' in scope
  11 | 
  12 |   public required init(appContext: AppContext) {
  13 |     urlSessionDelegate = URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy(dispatchQueue: fetchRequestQueue)


❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoURLSessionTask.swift:19:25)

  17 |   func start(
  18 |     urlSession: URLSession,
> 19 |     urlSessionDelegate: URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy,
     |                         ^ cannot find type 'URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy' in scope
  20 |     url: URL,
  21 |     requestInit: NativeRequestInit,
  22 |     requestBody: Data?


❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/ExpoURLSessionTask.swift:46:35)

  44 |   }
  45 | 
> 46 |   func cancel(urlSessionDelegate: URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy) {
     |                                   ^ cannot find type 'URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy' in scope
  47 |     if let task {
  48 |       urlSessionDelegate.removeDelegate(task: task)
  49 |       task.cancel()


❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/NativeRequest.swift:19:25)

  17 |   func start(
  18 |     urlSession: URLSession,
> 19 |     urlSessionDelegate: URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy,
     |                         ^ cannot find type 'URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy' in scope
  20 |     url: URL,
  21 |     requestInit: NativeRequestInit,
  22 |     requestBody: Data?


❌  (../../node_modules/expo/ios/Fetch/NativeRequest.swift:33:35)

  31 |   }
  32 | 
> 33 |   func cancel(urlSessionDelegate: URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy) {
     |                                   ^ cannot find type 'URLSessionSessionDelegateProxy' in scope
  34 |     self.task.cancel(urlSessionDelegate: urlSessionDelegate)
  35 |     self.response.emitRequestCanceled()
  36 |   }

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RN]Check rncore' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Fabric' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RN]Check rncore' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this issue, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-FabricComponents' from project 'Pods')

› 7 error(s), and 4 warning(s)

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
       

The same project fails on Android with the following:
✔ Created native directory
✔ Updated package.json | no changes
✔ Finished prebuild
› Opening emulator Pixel_8_API_34
› Building app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip
.....................10%......................20%......................30%.....................40%......................50%......................60%......................70%.....................80%......................90%......................100%

Welcome to Gradle 8.10.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for Java 23
 - Faster configuration cache
 - Better configuration cache reports

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 ℹ️  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@4.0.29)
Errors during XML parse:
Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 35 in /Users/federicozivolo/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 35 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 35 in /Users/federicozivolo/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/35.0.0
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 35 v.35.0.0" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 35 in /Users/federicozivolo/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 35 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 35 in /Users/federicozivolo/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-35
"Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 35 (revision 1)" finished.

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-asset (11.0.0)
  - expo-blur (14.0.1)
  - expo-constants (17.0.2)
  - expo-dev-client (4.0.29)
  - expo-dev-launcher (4.0.29)
  - expo-dev-menu (5.0.23)
  - expo-file-system (18.0.0)
  - expo-font (13.0.1)
  - expo-haptics (14.0.0)
  - expo-json-utils (0.13.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (14.0.1)
  - expo-linear-gradient (14.0.1)
  - expo-linking (7.0.2)
  - expo-manifests (0.14.3)
  - expo-modules-core (1.12.26)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.29.4)
  - expo-system-ui (4.0.2)
  - expo-web-browser (14.0.0)


> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.6.0
Gradle: 8.10.2

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
/Users/federicozivolo/.gradle/caches/8.10.2/transforms/f7b7de1a73e75965203beef3c2bd3564/transformed/material-1.6.1/res/values/values.xml:224:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.

> Task :expo-file-system:processDebugManifest
/Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/node_modules/expo-file-system/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:6:9-8:20 Warning:
        provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:6 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/workspaces/mobile-client/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1377b920.). Check logs for more details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 45s
167 actionable tasks: 114 executed, 53 from cache
Error: /Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/workspaces/mobile-client/android/gradlew app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/workspaces/mobile-client/android/gradlew app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:67:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:28:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.ts:134:28)
    at assembleAsync (/Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.ts:83:16)
    at runAndroidAsync (/Users/fezvrasta/Developer/myproject/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/run/android/runAndroidAsync.ts:48:24)
        

When I try to run the Android build on Expo EAS I get the following:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /home/expo/workingdir/build/workspaces/mobile-client/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/release/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@586ce3e7.). Check logs for more details.


Try running npx expo-doctor to see if there are any issues with your project and its dependencies.  Also, try npx expo install --check or npx expo install --fix.

@GregFenton Expo Doctor reports all okay, same for expo install

Consider doing an eas build in the cloud to see if the build fails there.  If it doesn't fail there, then it is your local machine's configuration (Xcode, Android Studio, java, ruby, cocoapods, etc.) that has the issue.
